# Literature review both by keywords in title and sorting by publishing date

Tags: literature-review, literature-search, literature

Is there any **free** online databases where I can do literature review by

(1)  giving keyword(s) that occur in **title**

(2) at the same time, sorting by publishing date from newest to oldest?

I found google scholar meets criteria (1) but it sorts by date only for one recent year. Pubmed meets criteria (2) but I am not finding option to search by (1) in pubmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PubMed permits title-only searches through its advanced search option:

[image]

This gives you many options, including a title-only search:

[image]

Also, you could use the advanced search syntax to search. After doing an advanced search, the syntax will display so that you can use it for faster searching later. For example, to search all PubMed articles that contain "open source" in the title, you search with `"open source"[Title]`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Scopus](http://www.scopus.com) or [Web of Science](http://www.webofscience.com)? Both feature extensive searching filter and sorting options for all fields of science.

Comment: OP asked for FREE databases. The entire point of the question, as I understand it, is that free databases don't seem to give as many search options as the subscription-based ones (which is not quite the case, at least in the case of PubMed).

Comment: I missed that (bold) "free" bit, sorry!